# Prettier/ESLint incorrectly corrects Next.js

Tags: next.js, eslint, prettier

I'm building an app with Next.js 13 using the app router, but I am encountering an error with formatting. Here is the code snippet:

[image]

However, after saving the file with Prettier/ESLint, the formatting becomes incorrect:

[image]

The issue lies with Prettier/ESLint incorrectly formatting the 'useClient' part.

My .prettierc file:

```
{
    "editorconfig": true,
    "semi": false,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "singleQuote": true,
    "arrowParens": "always"
}
```

My .editorconfig file:

```
root = true

[*]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 3
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = false
```

My eslintrc:

```
{
    "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "prettier"]
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "tv-calendar",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@prisma/client": "4.15.0",
        "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
        "next": "13.4.4",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "zod": "^3.21.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
        "@types/node": "20.2.5",
        "@types/react": "18.2.9",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
        "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
        "eslint": "8.42.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "13.4.4",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
        "postcss": "8.4.24",
        "prisma": "^4.15.0",
        "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
        "typescript": "5.1.3"
    }
}
```

I made some modifications to the .prettierc file, such as removing the "arrowParens" configuration, but unfortunately, it did not produce the desired effect.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the 'use client' to the top of your file. By doing this, you can ensure that the formatting issue caused by Prettier/ESLint is resolved.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.